# How to compute column-wise logical evaluation of lists in R?

Tags: r

Say I have two lists:

```
list1 <- list(c(32, 43, 42))
list2 <- list(c(42, 46, 42))
```

How do I compute a column-wise (position-wise?) evaluation of the values stored across those lists? For example, I would like to calculate the number of events in each respective column that is greater than 40. So my results would be `1` for the first column, `2` for the second column, and `2` for the third column.

Is there a straightforward way to do this in R? I'm only finding resources for computing the mean down a column instead of a count-greater-than. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get this by loopiing over the `list` and applying `rowSums`

```
rowSums(sapply(list(list1, list2), function(x) do.call(rbind, x) > 40))
#[1] 1 2 2
```

---

Or if there is only a single `list` element, it can be converted to `vector`

```
rowSums(cbind(unlist(list1), unlist(list2)) > 40)
#[1] 1 2 2
```

Comment: This is great, thank you @akrun! Quick question: What if the lists are stored in a dataframe column? So `list1` would be in the first row, `list2` in the second row, etc. Does the same logic apply?

Comment: @R.Baratheon. If the lists are stored iin a `data.frame. then do `colSums(do.call(rbind, df1$col)> 40)` if it is not nested

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: I'm curious-- Say instead of evaluating `> 40` I wanted to evaluate the maximum. (That is, how many times a value is the maximum across lists.) Does that process follow similar logic to what you've outlined? Thanks again.

Comment: @R.Baratheon Are you checking for the whole `max` across both lists. i.e. `max(c(unlist(list1), unlist(list2))` i.e. `rowSums(cbind(unlist(list1), unlist(list2)) == max(c(unlist(list1), unlist(list2)))`

Comment: I'm realizing now that this is probably a separate question. I'll post one on a separate thread. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We can combine the two lists using `rbind`/`cbind`, compare with 40 and use `rowSums`/`colSums` to calculate number of values that are greater than 40.

With `rbind` and `colSums`

```
colSums(rbind(list1[[1]], list2[[1]]) > 40)
#[1] 1 2 2
```

With `cbind` and `rowSums`

```
rowSums(cbind(list1[[1]], list2[[1]]) > 40)
#[1] 1 2 2
```